# Why the download link is opening the image

Tags: javascript, html

The code has to download a file but it opens the file .What I am doing wrong ?

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the Image to download the image:<p>

<a href="/website/image1.jpg" download>
<img src="/website/image1.jpg" alt="Image" width="104" height="142">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code opens the file and doesn't download.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the top of your file, for letting your browser know that you are using HTML5.

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 1):

This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

If/when you start hosting it on a web server, this will start working. If you're just doing this for yourself on your computer, check out WAMP for Windows or MAMP for macOS to get started with Apache. [research link](https://www.reddit.com/r/HTML/comments/66nttm/download_attribute_not_working_properly/)

So simple solution regarding this issue. You just need to put your html file into a server.

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute is not totally supported by browsers, take a look at https://caniuse.com/#feat=download.

To be sure that browser will offer user to save file instead of opening it inside the browser window you should serve image from the server with content-type set to `application/octet-stream`.

The proper way to set header depends on backend technology stack you use.

Probably the easiest way to do it is to check the request at web server layer and then add header. For example, the config for nginx could be something like that:

```
location ~* .\?download$  {
  add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
}
```

This should open `image.jpg` in browser as usual, but `image.jpg?download` should offer user to save it.

The syntax of config file should be checked, I'm not *very* sure about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply where do I set it ?

Comment: @priyakalashi I updated the answer with possible solution

Answer (score -2):

The code looks fine to me.
But, please remind that download attribute its not supported in Edge version 12, IE, Safari 10 (and earlier), or Opera version 12 (and earlier).

Edit: Maybe it's because of the declaration of an HTML document missing.

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Comment: Please, consider marking this response as right if it solved your problem.